# NVMe overheating, blank screen

Tags: linux-mint, overheating, nvme

I'm using a Lenovo Ideacenter 510 but with Linux Mint currently on my machine. For some reason every time there are big updates or any heavy task, the process always keeps my NVMe SSD temp high as over 80°, then at some point my screen goes blank. When I restart my computer it comes back like nothing happened.

Is there a way preventing this from happening? Is there a a way of slowing down maybe? I tried to turn off swap, but the temperature is still shooting up from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's overheating. What is the internal condition of the machine? I recommend compressed air for getting rid of the worst of the dust (outdoors, of course). Then gently vacuum it out. Use a fine artists toothbrush to gently stir up the dust and hold a vacuum nearby to suck it up. If you've never looked inside a computer you may be surprised at how dirty they get.